# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift

I get this Error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

When I call this function:

```
ViewController().textToLabel(answer: answerLabel)
```

I call this from a different class:

```
func textToLabel(answer: String){
      answerLabel.text = answer           //I get the error here
}
```

Second View Controller

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class germanClass{

    func forGerman(){

        var answerLabel = ""
        var voiceText = ""
        var colorPicker = "white"

        var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numberOfAnswers + 1))

        switch (randomNumber){
        case 0...20:
            answerLabel = "Ja"
            voiceText = "Ja"
            colorPicker = "green"
        }

        //ViewController().changeColor(color: colorPicker)
        ViewController().textToLabel(answer: answerLabel)

        if (voiceTextOn){
            randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(7))
            if (randomNumber == 0){
                if (userName != "Ich möchte wissen wie du heißt! " || userName != "du"){
                    voiceText += userName
                }
            }
        }
        textToSpeech().siriVoice(language: "de-de", text: voiceText)
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't see any force unwrapping in the code you posted. The problem is happening somewhere else. Post the relevant code based on the line number in the error.

Comment: It might be easier to answer your question if you included the code for the `ViewController` class.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've shown, I'd say you are sending a label where you should be sending label.text
Either send the text or send the label and define your method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ViewController().textToLabel(answer: answerLabel)` will instantiate a new `ViewController` and call `textToLabel(answer:)` on it, which is probably not what you want.

If you're trying to pass data between two view controllers you will have to find some other way to do it, depending on the relationship between them.

Also, your second view controller should inherit from `UIViewController` (as any view controllers should).